# Running Linux program using Windows DLL (winelib) without wine?

Tags: android, c++, linux, wine, winelib

I have a Windows DLL and an API related to the DLL. The DLL is part of a driver of specific device, for which I would like to write a Linux (Android 4.0) software. I've read that it is possible to use a DLL inside Linux software (using [winelib](http://wiki.winehq.org/Winelib)).

If I do so, can I run my program **without** wine (using native Linux environment, with the DLL attached)?
I am going to use Java (Android SDK), C++ (Android NDK) and possibly C (needed to write Linux driver working with the DLL).

Comment: Have you read the documentation for winelib?

Comment: Yes but I've found answers that seemed contradictory: http://wiki.jswindle.com/index.php/WineLib#Calling_a_Native_Windows_dll_from_Linux (says I can do it without wine), whereas the other (can't find the direct link) said I should use wine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I've read that it is possible to use a DLL inside Linux software (using winelib).

Very few Android devices run on x86 processors. Zero Windows apps are written for ARM CPUs (the dominant CPU architecture for Android).

Ergo, you cannot use a Windows DLL on the vast majority of Android devices, regardless of WINE.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get the company that wrote the DLL to build it targeting arm (with win8 / vs2012) and run that under Wine, but it's a long shot.  If you have the source code for the DLL, you could try compiling the dll with WinMaker, which is part of WineLib.